# How can I update my PATH in using expect in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I'm connecting to my university server using ssh. But, every time I log in I have to update my `R` PATH. So, I would like to automatize it, I have this script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh user@server

expect "password:"
send "<pass>\r"
send 'export PATH=/usr/local/R-3.1.2/bin/:$PATH" R "$@"\r"
send 'R\r'

interact
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just set the path in your `~/.bash_profile` file on the server?

Comment: How can I do that?, I'm a newbie using Linux.

Comment: Also, I'm not a superuser.

Comment: Log into the server, use an editor to edit (or create) the file `.bash_profile` in your home directory there. Add `export PATH=/usr/local/R-3.1.2/bin/:$PATH` to that file. Exit and log in again. `R` will now be in your path.

Comment: @Kusalananda  Is it possible that I need to include other paths' in this new ".bash_profile". I'm suspecting that because tar is not working now...

Comment: Make sure that you set the path as `PATH=/usr/local/R-3.1.2/bin/:$PATH` (i.e. include the old path value at the end).

Comment: Man, I'm having  big issues now, I simply can't decompress my files. Tar is not working... I actually deleted the `bash_profile`, log out, and log in again, and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Take note that single quotes have **no** special meaning in expect (which is an extension of Tcl). Tcl has [different quoting characters](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm).

I assume you want to make the remote connection, set the path and call R with the rest of the arguments. Tcl stores the command line arguments in the `$argv` variable

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh user@server

expect "password:"
send "<pass>\r"
# $PATH is already exported
send "PATH=/usr/local/R-3.1.2/bin/:\$PATH\r"
send [join [concat R $argv]]
sent "\r"

# do you then want to drop into an interactive R session?
send 'R\r'
interact
```